# $onInit does not immediately have bindings data

Tags: angularjs

I have this component in my app:

```
<actions-bar actions="$ctrl.actionsBarData"></actions-bar>
```

Here is the controller / component definition:

```
.component('actionsBar', {
    controller: 'actionsBarController',
    bindings: {
        actions: '<'
    }
})

.controller('actionsBarController', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.$onInit = function() {
        console.log(vm.actions);
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(vm.actions);
        }, 500);
    };
});
```

Take note of the two `console.log` statements within `$onInit`. In the browser the first logging statement prints `undefined`. The second statement, wrapped in `setTimeout` correctly prints out the `this.actions` object.

According to the Angular docs:

> $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an
>   element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized

If the bindings have been initialized, why is the data not immediately available? Why must I set a delay of 500ms before it is available?

If `$onInit` isn't the solution here,  how can I reliably access the bindings data within my controller? It appears that this is correct lifecycle hook to use, and none of the other hooks appear to be what I want in this case.

Comment: can you add some info about the provenance of $ctrl.actionsBarData

Comment: it is not possible actually if the actions is already defined at parent. Can you check that do you have actions data on parent scope?

Comment: `$ctrl.actionsBarData` is immediately available upon initialization based on some logging statements I added to the parent component's controller. As far as I can tell, it's an issue of data that is "immediately" (relatively speaking, for all intents and purposes) available at the parent level but not immediately available to the child through `$onInit`.

Comment: Fortunately fixed in 1.6 but quite a refactor to get to that stage (all controllers need to move intialisation into $onInit...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because while the bindings have been initialized in the controller, they haven't necessarily been initialized where they are coming from. If you are populating your binding with an async call, the object is going to be undefined or empty.

$onChanges allows you to inspect changes that happen to your bindings.

```
vm.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
    console.log(changesObj.actions);
}
```

If what I described above is happening, this will fix it for you.

EDIT: a word

Comment: Using this lifecycle hook, on initialization the same logging that I reported above happens (init appears to register as a "change"), but then when the binding changes it fires the loggers again, this time with the correct data in both instances. So this is definitely a working solution, I guess I misinterpreted the "bindings initialized" part of $onInit, due to the async nature of the code.